# Transportable Tablespace Importing error ORA-39070, ORA-39087

Tags: oracle, oracle21c

I have this import that is just showing:

```
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-39087: directory name DIR_PDB1 is invalid
```

This is my command for importing:

```
!impdp DIRECTORY =DIR_PDB1 DUMPFILE=T1.dmp nologfile job_name=imp_T1 transport_datafiles='/u01/app/oracle/oradata/ORCL/pdb1/T1.dbf'

and this is my command for the directory
create or replace DIRECTORY DIR_PDB1 as '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/ORCL/pdb1/DIR_PDB1';
```

Inside the dir_pdb1 i have T1.dmp and in T1.dbf

```
!impdp DIRECTORY =DIR_PDB1 DUMPFILE=T1.dmp nologfile job_name=imp_T1 transport_datafiles='/u01/app/oracle/oradata/ORCL/pdb1/T1.dbf'
!impdp DUMPFILE=T1.dmp DIRECTORY=DIR_PDB1 transport_datafiles='T1.dbf' remap_schema=T1:T1_new logfile=tts_import.log
!impdp DIRECTORY =DIR_PDB1 DUMPFILE=T1.dmp remap_tablespace=t1
renaming the directory
```

I did all that but it still has those error ORA-39070, ORA-39087

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a constructive statement as it does not tell us which bit does not work or what the error was.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and ensure the formatting is correct. I've done my best to improve it but its still not entirely clear.

Comment: thankyou for helping im pretty much new